# How to insert one line code in the middle of the html file by using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have one html file named Hello.html,

**Hello.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Window Title or Email Subject</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<!--@SPF-JS-HEADER@-->
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I wish to add few line which is

```
<style type="text/css">
table.tblin, td.tblin, th, td.alt 
{
     border-color:#cc9;
     border-collapse:collapse;
     border-style:solid;
     border-width:1px;
     border-spacing:4px;
}
```

So i wish to used the python code just insert the style script and the output like below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Window Title or Email Subject</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<!--@SPF-JS-HEADER@-->
<style type="text/css">
table.tblin, td.tblin, th, td.alt 
{
     border-color:#cc9;
     border-collapse:collapse;
     border-style:solid;
     border-width:1px;
     border-spacing:4px;
} 
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = """<style type="text/css">
table.tblin, td.tblin, th, td.alt
{
     border-color:#cc9;
     border-collapse:collapse;
     border-style:solid;
     border-width:1px;
     border-spacing:4px;
}
"""    # make a string of your required text to be appended

with open('train.html', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith('<!--@SPF-JS-HEADER@-->'):   # find a pattern so that we can add next to that line
            lines[i] = lines[i]+a
    f.truncate()
    f.seek(0)                                           # rewrite into the file
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: Hi, this code can work but <!--@SPF-JS-HEADER@-->' already being erase

Comment: I replace lines[i] to lines[i+1], it work be it will have extra string like after the <!--@SPF-JS-HEADER@-->' is will start with P symbol

Comment: but i notice there is an automatically creating symbol appear in front of the text, any ideas to get it out?

Comment: Add f.truncate() before f.seek(0) and try

Comment: Hi, I still face the same issue

Comment: I am getting correct results. Anyway I updated the code a little. Can you try now?

Comment: Hi, I face the same issue too, even though I follow exactly, it still auto generate a "P".

Comment: What 'r+' means comparing to 'r' ?